# Unable to extract jsonpath in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jsonpath

I am using jsonpath.com to evaluate my jsonpath expression.

```
$.[?(@.ContractId=='ДГМ-313349')].[*].ContactPerson[0].[*].Email
```

So I successfully evaluate my jsonpath on this page (see: https://snag.gy/LqSEy0.jpg) and get string what I need.
But when I insert my jsonpath expression in Jmeter to JSON path assertion and run test - it fails. Jsonpath assertion always finds empty string. I am using plugin from JP@GC. Is any difference between syntaxes of these json extractors? I also used JSON Path extractor and extract json from variable. The result is the same.

Comment: I guess it's an encoding problem. To verify that try searching for `latin-1` string first. Converting Cyrillic characters through `native2ascii` might help as well but that depends on that plugin code.

Comment: I've replaced string and now it doesn't contain any cyrillic symbols but It still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved problem. There was a dot missing after "$":

```
$..[?(@.ContractId=='ДГМ-313349')].[*].ContactPerson[0].[*].Email
```